If Migration is not sent to the database, UseExceptionHandler Middleware will not work. Why?
I added a new property in a entity class. I didn't create migration. After that, I tried to use UseExceptionHandler middleware. It successfully triggered error action method but the view didn't appear. Instead, the default developer exception page was displayed. I wonder why this happened. Later, I added new migration and updated the database. After doing so, the middleware worked as expected.
I tried to use UseExceptionHandler middleware. The view didn't appear.

select [newcolumn] will throw an exception if it doesn't exist. I'm not sure why you are surprised by that.

I know it. Maybe It could be a compiler error. Error action method had ran but custom view didn't seem.

Hi @Onur，Is your problem solved? what can I do for you?

Enables the Developer Exception Page when ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development. This is done automatically by the WebApplication.CreateBuilder method.
Calls UseExceptionHandler when the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is anything other than Development. you can delete "!" or remove the judgment condition.
Here's an example：
1） delete "!"
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

2）remove the judgment condition
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();

The result is as follows:

